# Find all Dropbox Folders using Dropbox API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, getjson, dropbox-api

I started with this stackoverflow question and answer, an excellent start, thank you. [Trying to walk a dropbox folder tree with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7544742/1877283)
but I'm not using node.js.  I'm using straight Javascript.  I'm not sure about the counter increment and decrement referred to in the answer - not sure where they would go.

I'm using jQuery.getJSON to grab the metadata.  Basically I'm lost at this point.  I can get the metadata from dropbox but I'm having trouble processing the function pathsToArray.

The function dbxGetContents is just a function I set up to perform another call to Dropbox to get the folder contents of the folder just found.

```
function dbxCreateTree(clickFolderName, crumbType, crumbData){

    // Get the OAUTH connection to Dropbox.  It's a call to the JS function dbxConnect()
    var dbxConn = dbxConnect();

    var dbxUrlTree = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/" + clickFolderName;       
    dbxUrlTree = dbxUrlTree + "?";
    dbxUrlTree = dbxUrlTree + dbxConn;

    jQuery.getJSON(dbxUrlTree,
        function(data){

            function pathsToArray(metadataarr,callback){   //Call this function and pass the Dropbox metadata array to it, along with a callback function
                    for (aItem in metadataarr ){  //For every folder or file in the metadata(which represents a specific URL)
                            if (metadataarr[aItem].is_dir){     //It is a folder
                                dropbox.paths.push(metadataarr[aItem].path+"/");   //Write the path of the folder to my array called 'dropbox.paths'
                                dbxGetContents(metadataarr[aItem].path.slice(1),function(err, data){   //We go into the folder-->Call the dropbox API to get metadata for the path of the folder.
                                    if (err){  
                                    }
                                    else {      
                                        pathsToArray(data.contents,function(err){  //Call the function from within itself for the url of the folder.  'data.contents' is where the metadata returned by Dropbox lists files/folders
                                        }); 
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else {      //It is a file
                                //dropbox.paths.push(metadataarr[aItem].path);   //Write the path of the file to my array called 'dropbox.paths'
                            }
                        }
            return callback(); //This returns multiple times, instead of only once when everything is ready, and that is the problem!
            };

        pathsToArray(data);

        });     
}
```

Here is the dbxGetContents function.

```
function dbxGetContents(dbxFolderName){

        // Get the OAUTH connection to Dropbox.  It's a call to the JS function dbxConnect()
        alert('here in dbxGetContents looking for ' + dbxFolderName);
        var dbxConn = dbxConnect();

        var dbxUrlTree = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/" + dbxFolderName;     
        dbxUrlTree = dbxUrlTree + "?";
        dbxUrlTree = dbxUrlTree + dbxConn;

        jQuery.getJSON(dbxUrlTree,
            function(data){
                alert('here returning data');
                return data;
                }
            );
    }
```

Thanks very much for looking.

Comment: I think I'm going about this the wrong way.  I don't think you need to step through the Dropbox hierarchy grabbing folders.

Using the Dropbox API call /Delta, a POST Ajax call will result in an "entries" list of all items in the Dropbox.  I'm getting all the data returned and now I'm working on parsing it.

I'll come back here and post the full solution when it's done.  I just didn't want anyone wasting their time in the interim.

Comment: Also interested in where you got with this.